# MatSnackBar: Colors have no effect

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have trouble adding a CSS class to [MatSnackBar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview).

```js
this._snackBar.open('✔ Saved', '', {
  duration: 3000,
  horizontalPosition: 'right',
  panelClass: ['snackbar-success']
});
```

```css
.snackbar-success
  background: $success
  color: #fff
```

It used to work before but since I have updated Angular Material to 17.0.4, it doesn't work anymore. I now have updated to 17.0.5 and it still does not work.

Basically, the CSS class is getting added but it has no effect. It seems as if it is being added in the wrong place.

This is what i see in DOM:

[image]

`display: none !important` works but in my case I am using colors. I tried `color`, `background`, `background-color`, and all of them with `!important` but none of them worked.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how you can change the colors of mat-snackbar:

```css
.mat-mdc-snack-bar-container.snackbar-success {
  --mat-mdc-snack-bar-button-color: #fff;
  --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #28a745;
  --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `--mdc-snackbar-container-color:  $success` did not work for me. I have changed it to `--mdc-snackbar-container-color: #{$success}` and now it works fine.